# How to put jqm data-role="page" in a MVC view page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-mobile, razor

I'm using MVC3 to create a beta mobile web app. It was working fine until I started to try and get inline pages inside of a view similar to [this](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/toolbars/docs-navbar.html)

This is what I currently have in my view called Index. How come when I click the links in the navbar it doesn't go to the page?

```
@model List<ShawGoVersion1.Models.NewsItem>

@{
     ViewBag.Title = "News";
 }

@section Header {
@Html.ActionLink("Back", "Index", "Home", null, new { data_icon = "arrow-l"})
<h1>@ViewBag.Title</h1>
<div data-role="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#MyNews">My News</a></li>
            <li><a href="#PressReleases">Press Releases</a></li>
            <li><a href="#AllNews">All News</a></li>
        </ul>
</div>
}

<div data-role="page" id="MyNews">
    <div data-role="content">
        <h1>This feature coming soon</h1>
    </div>
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="AllNews">
    <div data-role="content">    
        <ul data-role="listview">
            @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++ )
            {
                if (Model[i].type == "Article")
                {
                    <li>
                        <a href="@Url.Action("NewsItemDetails", "News", new { id = i })">
                            @if (Model[i].pictureURL != null)
                            {
                                <div class="ui-grid-c">
                                    <div class="ui-block-a" style="width:31%;vertical-align:middle">
                                        <img src="@Model[i].pictureURL" style="width:100%;height:auto"/>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="ui-block-b" style="width:4%; vertical-align:middle"></div>
                                    <div class="ui-block-c" style="width:65%;vertical-align:middle">
                                        <h3 style="font-size:small; white-space:normal">@Model[i].title</h3>
                                        <p><strong>@Model[i].date.ToShortDateString()</strong></p>
                                    </div> 
                                </div>
                            }
                            else
                            {   
                                <h3 style="font-size:small; white-space:normal">@Model[i].title</h3>
                                <p><strong>@Model[i].date.ToShortDateString()</strong></p>
                            }                                                   
                        </a>
                    </li>
                }  
            }    
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>


<div id="PressReleases" data-role="page">
    <div data-role"content">
        <ul data-role="listview">
            @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++ )
            {
                if (Model[i].type == "Press Release")
                {
                    <li>
                        <a href="@Url.Action("NewsItemDetails", "News", new { id = i })">
                            @if (Model[i].pictureURL != null)
                            {
                                <div class="ui-grid-c">
                                    <div class="ui-block-a" style="width:31%;vertical-align:middle">
                                        <img src="@Model[i].pictureURL" style="width:100%;height:auto"/>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="ui-block-b" style="width:4%; vertical-align:middle"></div>
                                    <div class="ui-block-c" style="width:65%;vertical-align:middle">
                                        <h3 style="font-size:small; white-space:normal">@Model[i].title</h3>
                                        <p><strong>@Model[i].date.ToShortDateString()</strong></p>
                                    </div> 
                                </div>
                            }
                            else
                            {   
                                <h3 style="font-size:small; white-space:normal">@Model[i].title</h3>
                                <p><strong>@Model[i].date.ToShortDateString()</strong></p>
                            }                                                   
                        </a>
                    </li>
                }  
            }    
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your navbar should appear within data-role="page". Within the data-role="page" you should have a data-role="header" and your navbar should go in there if you want it to be in the header of the jqm page.

Alternatively if you don't want to do it that way(which you should do, as its the correct way). You could try catch the onclick event of those links in your navbar yourself and then fire

```
$.mobile.changePage();
```

This may work.

Comment: thanks David, I tried your first suggestion and it didn't work, in fact I noticed another problem.. anything within a 
'<div data-role="page"></div>'
 doesn't show up on the page. Is there a default id for this kind of div that I need to set for it to show?

Comment: Hmm thats odd, when you view source is the data-role="page" there?

Comment: view source? I'm building in Visual Studio 2010 with MVC4 Razor markup

Comment: When you view the page in your browser, view the source code to see what the browser sees

Comment: I'm sorry I misunderstood your question. Yes, when I click view source in a browser it does show all the content including data-role="page"

Comment: Are there nested data-role="page" elements? From what I understand MVC 4 _layout.cshtml will have the data-role="page" div around the RenderBody() razor statement. So the code you have now will cause the data-role="page" elements to be nested within the parent one, which causes issues.

Comment: yes this is the body of the _Layout.cshtml file

`<body>
        <div data-role="page" data-theme="b">
            <div data-role="header">
                @if (IsSectionDefined("Header")) {
                    @RenderSection("Header")
                } else {
                    <h1>@ViewBag.Title</h1>
                    @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
                }
            </div>
            <div data-role="content">
                @RenderBody()
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>`

Comment: The current way your project is layed out wont work. You cant have the data-role=page in the layout view and then the other view as well. As you will have data-role=page elements within data-role=page elements. You should instead do as I say and have the navbar in the data-role elements that are in your view, and then just remove all the jqm elements from _layout, and just leave @RenderBody. The way MVC4's mobile project type is designed is for multi-page layouts, what you're trying to achieve is a single-page layout

Comment: thanks David, I went ahead and made another layout file specifically for this page since all the other ones are standard. Removing the jqm elements from the layout file made it work